# List all factors of number

Tags: python, factors

I am trying to list all the factors of a number called count. Whenever I run it, it returns 1. For example: `if 6 = count`, then what should be returned when calling `findFactor(6)` is `1 2 3 6`. What is returned is 1

```
divisors = ""
def findFactor(count):
    divisors = ""
    valueD = 0
    for i in range(1, count+1):
        valueD = count/i
        if isinstance(valueD,int) == True:
            divisors = str(valueD)+" "
    print divisors
```

Comment: This isn't Java code. Did you by chance mean to use `python` tag?

Comment: try concatenating the results within the loop, something like `divisors += str(valueD)+" "`

Comment: @KenWhite you're right! i am so sorry, I meant to put python. Thank you!

Comment: @downshift you are right! thank you for editing it!

Comment: @downshift that seems to work however when it prints I get 28 14 9 7 5 4 4 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Comment: If this is Python 3, `if isinstance(valueD,int) == True` will never be true, if it is Python 2, it will *always* be True, assuming `count` is always an `int`

Comment: @ethanlee well, that's a different question, at least you've got different output now and can debug more

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how would I fix it? is there a way to tell if it is a double or an int

Comment: @downshift yes, thank you, I might just reiterate through it and remove any second instances. This doesn't need to be too optimized

Comment: Yes, you use `isinstance` but that isn't what you want to know. It is either *always* and `int`, or *always* a `float` (python doesn't have a `double` type)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok, i used a modulus operator instead to check if the return is 0

Comment: @ethanlee yes, that is the right way to do it!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer this code:

```
def find_factor(n):
  factor_values = []
  for i in range(1, n + 1):
    if n % i == 0:
      factor_values.append(i)

  values = ""
  for v in factor_values:
    values += str(v) + " "

  return values
```

The function will return `1 2 3 6`

Answer (score 6):

This can be done on one line using [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python).

```
def factorize(num):
    return [n for n in range(1, num + 1) if num % n == 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have an indentation error. `print divisors` need to be tabbed to inside the for-loop.

```
divisors = ""
def findFactor(count):
    divisors = ""
    valueD = 0
    for i in range(1, count+1):
        valueD = count/i
        if isinstance(valueD,int) == True:
            divisors = str(valueD)+" "
        print divisors
```

Furthermore like @juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned, your results will vary between Python 2 and Python 3.

However, if you want your `divisors` to print in the order you want, i.e. start with `1` you need to change your range to `for i in range(count,0, -1)`. You will get multiple `1`'s , but that's something I'll leave for you to figure out. A little challenge, if you will. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is the total code I have come up with. Thank you for all the help.

```
def findFactor(n):
  factorValues = []
  for i in range(1, n + 1):
    if n % i == 0:
      factorValues.append(i)

  values = ""
  for v in factorValues:
    values += str(v) + " "

  print values.count(" ")
  # prints the number of factors


  print values
findFactor(21)
```

It will print the number of factors, and then the factors on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

The answers given so far are all brute force methods.

For n=10000, they will have to iterate ten thousand times.

The following will iterate only 100 times:

```
def find_factors(n):
    factors = []
    i = 1
    j = n
    while True:
        if i*j == n:
            factors.append(i)
            if i == j:
                break
            factors.append(j)
        i += 1
        j = n // i
        if i > j:
            break
    return factors
```

If there were a list of prime numbers available, it could be made even faster.