# I am new to python and I am wondering why this while loop isn't working

Tags: python

It is meant to find all the factors for a number, can someone help me?
the error that its giving me is that it cant divide by zero, but it shouldn't be doing that by that point.

```
factored = False

number_s = input("What is the number\n")
number = (int(number_s))

while factored == False:
    factor_number = number
    factored_number = number / factor_number
    if factored_number == 0:
        break



    decimal = isinstance(factored_number, int)

    if decimal == False and factored_number <= number:
        print(factored_number)
        number = factored_number - 1
    else:
        pass

    if factored_number == number:
       break
```

Comment: In Python 3, the result of your division will always be a float, not an int. The `isinstance(factored_number, int)` will not tell you anything useful. I don't follow how this code is supposed to work.

Comment: `number / factor_number` will always result in a `float` object

Comment: You should look at other code examples such as [List all factors of number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064885/list-all-factors-of-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if the number is zero before you preform the operation.
For example

```
factored = False

number_s = input("What is the number\n")
number = (int(number_s))

while factored == False:
    factor_number = number
    #notice we are checking the user's number is == 0 before we even divide it.
    if factor_number == 0:
        break
    factored_number = number / factor_number




    decimal = isinstance(factored_number, int)

    if decimal == False and factored_number <= number:
        print(factored_number)
        number = factored_number - 1
    else:
        pass

    if factored_number == number:
       break
```

I also hope you know there are much easier ways of doing this. For example, using modulus operation `%`. Here's an implementation using that.

```
x = 10
for i in range(1, x + 1):
       if x % i == 0:
           print(i)
```

output

```
1
2
5
10
```